# Failed to get properties: No such interface '' in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, services, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I Created this Unit file `tdk-api.service` in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder with this permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x`

with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description = tdk API daemon

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart =  /usr/local/bin/start-tdk-api.sh
ExecStop =   /usr/local/bin/stop-tdk-api.sh
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/reload-tdk-api.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

But I have an error when starting:

```
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl start tdk-api
Failed to start tdk-api.service: Unknown unit: tdk-api.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status tdk-api.service' for details.
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status tdk-api.service
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system#
```

I also tried to reload systemd daemon, as suggested

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

I also tried:

```
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl enable tdk-api.service
Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/tdk-api.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tdk-api.service, pointing to /etc/systemd/system/tdk-api.service.
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# sudo systemctl start tdk-api
Failed to start tdk-api.service: Unknown unit: tdk-api.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status tdk-api.service' for details.
root@localhost:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status tdk-api.service
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
```